# box2d ragdoll: how to prevent jitters?

Tags: box2d

I am using as3 version of box2d.
I need to create a human body: I used some boxes+ joints: works fine.
**Trouble is it never sleeps: it jitters all the time !**

I tried with some propetries like density, dambing, velocityThreshold without sucess.

Can some give a clue ?

regards

Comment: What are your values for position and velocity iterations?

Comment: position : it falls down.
veolicty iteration : default value (I don't know to be honnest)

Comment: When you call `world->Step`, what are the values you pass in as parameters?

Comment: I don't call it at all. I use WCK : http://www.sideroller.com/wck/

Answer (score -1):

Increase its physics simulation frequency, i.e. call world->Step more frequently with smaller time slices.